# How to create an XCUIElement query for the last UITableViewCell in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitableview, xctest

I am creating an `XCTestCase`. For one of the test methods, call it `func testConfirmLastCellContent() { ... }`, I want to confirm that there exists a `staticText` child element having a value of `"98765"` within a `UITableViewCell` (I put the text value in in the `textLabel.text` property of the table view cell). There are 4 table view cells listed above this cell. Each of them has a `String` value of `"12345"` for its `textLabel.text`, except for the second cell, which has the same text value as the last: `"98765"`.

The `String` values for the `textLabel.text` property of each cell, then, looks like this:

- `"12345"`
- `"98765"`
- `"12345"`
- `"12345"`
- `"98765"`

These `textLabel.text` values are the *only* visual sub-elements within the table view cells respectively.

If I create a simple `XCUIElementQuery` like so...

```swift
let staticTextForLastCell = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["98765"]
```

...and assert its existence as `true` like so...

```swift
XCTAssert(staticTextForLastCell.exists == true)
```

...then the test will *pass*, but how do I know I got the last cell? Obviously, I cannot know from that query, because it could be pulling from the 2nd cell.

Thus far, I cannot find an `XCTest` class/method to get ahold of the last `UITableViewCell` specifically and query its details.

My goal is to get the last cell and confirm its `textLabel.text` value is something I expect. How can I do this?

**Note:** I cannot add/subtract/change textual, visual, etc. elements on any of the table view cells.

**Edit:**

I should also note that the `UITableViewCell`s are generated dynamically by the app being tested. So, I cannot `tag` them or populate the `accessibilityIdentifier` property for the `textLabel` or the cell.

**My setup is the following:**

- *Operating System*: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- *IDE*: Xcode 10.3
- *SDK*: iOS 12.4 SDK
- *Deploy Target*: iOS 12.0
- *Language*: Swift 5

Comment: a "dirty" trick could be that you set the tag for the lastCell to 1 and all other cells to 0. Then you confirm also that the tag is 1 in your test case.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that `exists` is a Boolean value, so you don't have to compare it to `true` in an assertion. Simply write  `XCTAssert(staticTextForLastCell.exists)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add an extension to `XCUIElementQuery`

```
extension XCUIElementQuery {
    var lastMatch : XCUIElement {return self.element(boundBy: self.count - 1)}
}
```

Then you can assert your cell like this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.cells.lastMatch.staticTexts.element.label, 
               "98765", 
               "Unexpected text of the last cell")
```

Comment: I'm getting something like this: "Value of type 'XCUIElementQuery' has no member 'label'" when I try to build

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixed my answer.

Comment: Nice. This looks like a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works...

```swift
let app = XCUIApplication()
let cells = app.cells
let lastCell = cells.element(boundBy: cells.count - 1)
let textOfLastCell = lastCell.staticTexts["98765"]
XCTAssert(textOfLastCell.exists)
```

**Note**: Smart Monkey's answer used an extension, which may be advisable. The above is a more inline way.

**Edit**: I previously stated that I could not get it to work without querying for `tables` before querying for `cells`. It *does work* without the `tables` query.

**Edit**: Changed `XCTAssert(textOfLastCell.exists == true)` to `XCTAssert(textOfLastCell.exists)` based on comment from Chris. A bit cleaner.

Comment: I'm glad you made it work. 

I still recommend you to assert the label not the staticTexts existence. 

In case of test failure you'll get an error like "12345 is not equal to 98765" which a bit a bit more informative than just "98765 not found"

Comment: Great! That sounds like a better answer.